# SAP Enterprise Portal with thirdparty content

Tags: portlet, sap-enterprise-portal

Anyone integrated *SAP Enterprise Portal* with a third party web content management system (e.g. Vignette)? I don't have too much exposure to SAP Portal, but I know it provides a J2EE App Server and there are something called *iViews* which I would assume are some sort of fancy JSPs and Servlets etc.
Any insight will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iviews are component of a SAP Portal Page.

Such an Iview can be a SAP-kind-of-Servlet (DynPage or JSPDynPage), an URL, or part of the response of an URL (there are others type of iviews, such as webdynpro, SAP R/3 transaction, SAP BI request... but i don't think they will help you there). If you can integrate your CMS using JSP or URL, you're ok...

please see [SAPHelp](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/EN/18/66b742aec10b31e10000000a1550b0/frameset.htm) on the subject of portal component.

Note that there is also a KM system that can use/mount external resources (such as Documentum), but i don"t know much about this subject.

regarsd
Guillaume